# I am trying to update PHP Composer, but a problem arises

Tags: php, composer-php

From the command line, I issue:

```
composer install
```

#### Output

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/cache is locked to version v1.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/cache v1.8.0 requires php ~7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - doctrine/dbal is locked to version v2.9.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/dbal v2.9.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - doctrine/event-manager is locked to version v1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/event-manager v1.0.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that
requirement.
  Problem 4
    - doctrine/inflector is locked to version v1.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - maatwebsite/excel is locked to version 3.1.13 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.13 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 6
    - markbaker/complex is locked to version 1.4.7 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - markbaker/complex 1.4.7 requires php ^5.6.0|^7.0.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 7
    - markbaker/matrix is locked to version 1.1.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - markbaker/matrix 1.1.4 requires php ^5.6.0|^7.0.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 8
    - opis/closure is locked to version 3.2.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - opis/closure 3.2.0 requires php ^5.4 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 9
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet is locked to version 1.6.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.6.0 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
  Problem 10
    - ramsey/uuid is locked to version 3.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - ramsey/uuid 3.8.0 requires php ^5.4 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 11
    - renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed is locked to version 1.8.10 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed 1.8.10 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 12
    - symfony/psr-http-message-bridge is locked to version v1.2.0 and an update of this package was not
requested.
    - symfony/psr-http-message-bridge v1.2.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 13
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles is locked to version 2.2.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.1 requires php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 14
    - zendframework/zend-diactoros is locked to version 1.8.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - zendframework/zend-diactoros 1.8.6 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not
satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 15
    - composer/semver is locked to version 1.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - composer/semver 1.5.0 requires php ^5.3.2 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 16
    - composer/xdebug-handler is locked to version 1.3.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - composer/xdebug-handler 1.3.2 requires php ^5.3.2 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 17
    - doctrine/annotations is locked to version v1.6.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/annotations v1.6.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 18
    - doctrine/instantiator is locked to version 1.2.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/instantiator 1.2.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 19
    - facebook/webdriver is locked to version 1.6.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - facebook/webdriver 1.6.0 requires php ^5.6 || ~7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 20
    - filp/whoops is locked to version 2.3.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - filp/whoops 2.3.1 requires php ^5.5.9 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 21
    - friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer is locked to version v2.15.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer v2.15.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 22
    - fzaninotto/faker is locked to version v1.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - fzaninotto/faker v1.8.0 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 23
    - hamcrest/hamcrest-php is locked to version v2.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.    - hamcrest/hamcrest-php v2.0.0 requires php ^5.3|^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 24
    - myclabs/deep-copy is locked to version 1.9.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - myclabs/deep-copy 1.9.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 25
    - phar-io/manifest is locked to version 1.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phar-io/manifest 1.0.1 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 26
    - phar-io/version is locked to version 1.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phar-io/version 1.0.1 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that
requirement.
  Problem 27
    - php-cs-fixer/diff is locked to version v1.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - php-cs-fixer/diff v1.3.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 28
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock is locked to version 4.3.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 29
    - phpdocumentor/type-resolver is locked to version 0.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpdocumentor/type-resolver 0.4.0 requires php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 30
    - phpspec/prophecy is locked to version 1.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpspec/prophecy 1.8.0 requires php ^5.3|^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 31
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage is locked to version 5.3.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 5.3.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 32
    - phpunit/php-timer is locked to version 1.0.9 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/php-timer 1.0.9 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 33
    - phpunit/php-token-stream is locked to version 2.0.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/php-token-stream 2.0.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 34
    - phpunit/phpunit is locked to version 6.5.14 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.14 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 35
    - phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is locked to version 5.0.10 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 5.0.10 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 36
    - sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup is locked to version 1.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup 1.0.1 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 37
    - sebastian/comparator is locked to version 2.1.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/comparator 2.1.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 38
    - sebastian/diff is locked to version 2.0.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/diff 2.0.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 39
    - sebastian/environment is locked to version 3.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/environment 3.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 40
    - sebastian/exporter is locked to version 3.1.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/exporter 3.1.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 41
    - sebastian/global-state is locked to version 2.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.    - sebastian/global-state 2.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 42
    - sebastian/object-enumerator is locked to version 3.0.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/object-enumerator 3.0.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 43
    - sebastian/object-reflector is locked to version 1.1.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/object-reflector 1.1.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 44
    - sebastian/recursion-context is locked to version 3.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sebastian/recursion-context 3.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 45
    - theseer/tokenizer is locked to version 1.1.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - theseer/tokenizer 1.1.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 46
    - webmozart/assert is locked to version 1.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - webmozart/assert 1.4.0 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy th  Problem 47
    - doctrine/inflector v1.3.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/framework v5.5.45 requires doctrine/inflector ~1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0].
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v5.5.45 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

#### And:

```
composer update
```

#### Output

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, 1.16.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.16.0] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system.
Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.26].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Install or enable PHP's gd extension.

Comment: What have you tried to make this work? There are **multiple** hints within that error message, like using a compatible version fo PHP and installing some extension

Answer (score 36):

I used this command line and all of a sudden things happened like magic!

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: worked for me too (at least I could install the package).

Comment: What is the consequence of this? Presumably ignoring platform requirements? Are there some ill effects? Was it just bogus requirements (e.g., *"doctrine/cache v1.8.0 requires php ~7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement."*)? What is the explanation?

Comment: My first thought was exactly like @PeterMortensen said. This should be addressed in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, giving off a similar message:

```
Problem 1
- laminas/laminas-i18n[2.11.0, ..., 2.11.3] require php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (8.1.10) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laminas/laminas-i18n[2.12.0, ..., 2.18.0] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
- laminas/laminas-mvc-form 2.0.0 requires laminas/laminas-i18n ^2.11.2 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-i18n[2.11.2, ..., 2.18.0].
- Root composer.json requires laminas/laminas-mvc-form ^2.0.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-mvc-form[2.0.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php\php-8.1.10-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\php.ini
```

What I did here is that I opened the php configuration file (php.ini) located in the folder that path points to in the error message (C:\xampp\php\php.ini in your case), checked if the named extensions were commented (had ; in front).

I commented the needed ones out, and then checked if the extensions directory looked for extensions in the right folder (Most of the time it should be extension_dir = "ext"). In my case, this was commented, so the program didn't really know from where the extensions were to be loaded. Uncommenting that line solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

when you try as a very first time please use --ignore-platform-reqs.
this error occured due to your php version mismatching problems. then please use

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. There's a good reason that Composer throws this error message: the source code is not compatible with another PHP version. Installing it anyways makes no sense, as the application would not run properly, would it?

Comment: Also, please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights

Answer (score 0):

Solution is, going to root folder of PHP (probably in C:\Program Files\php or inside xampp\php) and search for php.ini file. Inside this file, find out the commented line ";extension=fileinfo" and delete the ";" so it gets uncommented ad save the file.
That was the problem for me.
Really dumb, but apparently no one fixes it by default.